# RXJS: split an observable, filter the results then re-combine

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a websocket that returns a stream of GPS NMEA sentences at a rate of 2Hz.  Each response typically contains six sentences including two GSV satellite visibility sentences and a GGA position fix sentence.  Each of the GSV sentences contains elevation, azimuth, and signal/noise ratio information for 1-4 satellites, these are the sentences I'm initially interested in.  I want to create an observable stream of `Satellite[]` arrays containing the elevation and azimuth details of the currently visible GNSS satellites.

The following typescript code fragments produce an array per `GSV` sentence, but what I would like to have is an array per response, which might include several GSV sentences.  I've looked into using concat, combine, merge, and their variants but with no success.

Eventually I also want to extract the GGA position fix information into another stream.

Apologies if there is a simple answer to this, I'm relatively new to RXJS so just finding my way.

```js
// The information available for each satellite.

export interface Satellite {
    id: string;
    elevation: number;
    azimuth: number;
    noise: number;
}


// The code to process the web socket data.

this.satellites$ = <Subject<Satellite[]>> this.wss
    .connect('ws://localhost:8887')
    .mergeMap((response) => { return response.data.split(/\r?\n/); }) // Split the multi line response into individual lines.
    .filter((line) => line !== '')  // Filter out blank lines.
    .mergeMap((sentence) => { return this.nmeaPacket(sentence); }) // Parse the line into an NMEA sentence.
    .filter((packet) => { return packet.sentenceId === 'GSV'; })  // Filter out everything except GSV sentences.
    .map((gsvPacket: nmea.GSVPacket): Satellite[] => {
        // Extract the satellite info from this sentence.
        let satellites: Satellite[] = [];
        for (let satellite of gsvPacket.satellites) {
            if (satellite.prnNumber > 1) {
                satellites.push({
                    id: this.satelliteId(satellite.prnNumber),
                    azimuth: satellite.azimuthTrue,
                    elevation: satellite.elevationDegrees,
                    noise: satellite.SNRdB})
            }
        }
        return satellites;
    });  // Re-combine the array here or back where the initial line split is done??


// Use nmea-simple to parse a line from the response into an NMEA sentence.
 
private nmeaPacket(sentence: any): Observable<nmea.Packet> {
    return Observable.of(nmea.parseNmeaSentence(sentence));
}
```

Below is a marble diagram with sample input data showing how I would like to process that data.  Hopefully this provides a clearer picture of what I am trying to achieve.

[marble diagram showing processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a0la.png)

Comment: Isn't just `bufferCount()` or `bufferTime()` what you're looking for?

Comment: i think you need to return an Observable from `mergeMap`: `.mergeMap(response => Observable.from(response.data.split(/\r?\n/)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question would benefit from an example of the input and desired output as I am not sure what re-combine the array actually means.

Also I am not sure that your code will produce the the behavior outlined in your comments. For instance `response.data.split(/\r?\n/)` returns an array but `.filter((line) => line !== '')` will return `true` only if `line` is a string and that string is empty.

Finally, it would help if you could clarify why `satellites$` is a Subject and not an `Observable` and `nmeaPacket` returns an observable as oppose to just `nmea.Packet`.

Having said that, let me suggest some adjustments and see if it helps:

```js
this.satellites$ = this.wss
  .connect('ws://localhost:8887')
  .map((response) => response.data.split(/\r?\n/).filter((line) => line !== '') // <- can you provide an example of the input here
  .map((sentence) => this.nmeaPacket(sentence))
  .filter((packet) => packet.sentenceId === 'GSV')
  .map((packet) => {
    let satellites: Satellite[] = [];
    packet.satellites.forEach((satellite) => {
    
      if (satellite.prnNumber > 1) {
        satellites.push({
          id: this.satelliteId(satellite.prnNumber),
          azimuth: satellite.azimuthTrue,
          elevation: satellite.elevationDegrees,
          noise: satellite.SNRdB})
        }
      }
      
      return satellites;
      
    })
  }) // <- can you provide an example of the desired output here

private nmeaPacket(sentence: any): nmea.Packet {
  return nmea.parseNmeaSentence(sentence);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Unitario, your response helped a little but not quite enough to solve my problem.  I've added a marble diagram which hopefully provides a clearer picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the diagram it is very clear. First I think you can change the type from Subject to Observable. The last map will indeed return an Observable containing an array of type Satellite, provided your code is correct so to speak. You can add .do((log) => console.log(log)) after each operator to see what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

To recombine the lines at the end you can swap out the last `map` by a `reduce`:

```
Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3).reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, value], []).subscribe(console.log)
```

(...but i'm not sure Observables are the correct tool here, are you sure you don't want to just map *every* response into some other shape? In this case a simple `.map` with synchronous filter/map operations would be sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks mkulke, this sounds like it might be the point I was missing.  I'll investigate this further.  In the meantime I have added a marble diagram that shows what I'm trying to achieve.  Originally I was going to use a BehaviorSubject in order to get the most recent satellite positions upon subscription (although this is not that critical), but my code has become a little confused in the process of trying to get things to work.

Comment: @DeanAshby: looking at that marble diagram it looks indeed like you only need to `.map` the response. judging from the last map fn in your code sample (imperatively filling an array), you're probably not familiar with functional tools for data transformation (i.e. map/filter/reduce...), but it's worth diving into that, things will get much simpler. So, i guess what you want to do is, _within a single map_ operation, you transform the response like this: `return response.data.split(byLine).filter(notEmpty).map(this.nmeaPacket).filter(isGSVSentence).map(toSatellites);`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the most efficient or elegant solution but it does achieve what I want.  There are a couple of places where I've had to iterate over the arrays of satellite info, I have experimented with flatMap/mergeMap in these places but haven't had much success.

```js
    private init() {

        this.satellites$ = this.wss
            .connect('ws://localhost:8887')
            .map((response: MessageEvent) => {
                    return response.data
                        .split(/\r?\n/)
                        .filter((x: string) => x !== '')
                        .map((x: string) => this.nmeaPacket(x))
                        .filter((x: nmea.Packet) => x.sentenceId === 'GSV')
                        .map((x) => this.toSatellites(x));
                })
            .map((x: Satellite[][]) => {
                let combined: Satellite[] = [];
                for (let group of x) {
                    combined = combined.concat(group);
                }
                return combined;
            });
    }

    private toSatellites(gsvPacket: nmea.GSVPacket): Satellite[] {
        let satellites: Satellite[] = [];
        for (let satellite of gsvPacket.satellites) {
            if (satellite.prnNumber > 1) {
                satellites.push({
                    id: this.satelliteId(satellite.prnNumber),
                    azimuth: satellite.azimuthTrue,
                    elevation: satellite.elevationDegrees,
                    noise: satellite.SNRdB});
            }
        }
        return satellites;
    }

    private nmeaPacket(nmeaSentence: any): nmea.Packet {
        return nmea.parseNmeaSentence(nmeaSentence);
    }
```